# How to make Ctrl-C, Ctrl-X work the same in Eclipse as IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> with text selected, the text is cut, but when there is nothing selected the current line is cut from the source.

Is there a way to have this key behavior in Eclipse?

Same for the copy functionality, but cut is more useful!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you very much.
Before reading your question, I was unaware that I was missing this Cut/Copy functionality.

So I looked around a bit, first inside Eclipse key binding system.  Then when I was convinced this functionality doesn't simply come "out of the box", I thought about writing a small Eclipse plugin.  But than I thought, "Why write bad lines of my own code, when so much somebody must have already wrote it and published it for everybody to enjoy?"

And so, a quick search yielded this [copycutcurrentline](http://code.google.com/p/copycutcurrentline/) little dropin.

I've installed it Eclipse 3.7 and it just works

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+d will work same as you think.

Comment: I want to maintain Ctrl-D's functionality from IntelliJ of duplication

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it will take some work: You will have to write a plugin for this. There is no hidden/unused key binding for this.

Answer (score 0):

"Alt + Up\Down Arrow Key" will do the trick to move an entire line up down in a single file.

"Ctrl + Shift + Up\Down Arrow Key" will help you duplicate the selection of line.

Not exactly what you want, but these 2 keyboard shortcuts are very useful.